# Download a secondary repo in Azure DevOps as part of build

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have 2 repos one which contains common build scripts for all projects and another repo is the actual project. They are using Git as the repo in Azure DevOps.

Currently when the build happens it only downloads the project repo but not able to force to download build script repo. Is it possible to download the build script repo with the project repo.

Comment: Hi,kumar Do you check answers given below? If you have any question,please feel free to ask.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT thanks for the suggestion. it was helpful. I had gone with git downloader extension for now.

Comment: Just an fyi, multi repo support has been added in the most recent release of azure devops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#multi-repo-checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to clone an additional repository when running a build.

As was already stated you could use a 'Command line' task and perform

```
git clone
```

However if you want to checkout additional repo's from your project you might want to use this extension from the marketplace as it handles the authentication from you more cleanly

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fakhrulhilal-maktum.GitDownloader&targetId=00da653d-4cf7-44d0-8bc8-42981743dc5c

Comment: I think there is a change in Azure Devops there is one more setting that need to enabled to the plugin to work. Go to the project select  and select "Project Settings"> Pipeline> Settings> Disable "Limit job authorization scope to current project"

Answer (score 2):

Currently [Multiple repo checkout](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/multicheckout.md) is not supported, however it's already in developing.
For now, as a workaround you could clone other repository programming to the working directory during the build, for example with classic pipelines:

1. Edit pipeline (build definition)
2. (Option) If the repositories are in different projects within the same organization: Select **Options** tab, select **Project collection** in **Build job authorization scope**
3. Switch to **Tasks** tab, select the **Agent Job** and Check **Allow
   scripts to access the OAuth token** option under **Additional
   options**
4. Add **Command line task** and run the following git command:  `git
   clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/TEST0625`, you can set the working directory as needed (e.g `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not natively that I know of, but you could just run a `git clone` command as the first task in your pipeline which will do the same thing. It might even be an even better approach as you could create a directory structure first then `git clone` so your reference to your build scripts will always be the same.